# Loop through sub-directories and call (powershell)script

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with several subfolders. A powershell-script is located in each subfolder. The name of the powershell is the same in every subfolder ('execute.ps1'). How can i recursively iterate through all subdirectories and call 'execute.ps1' ?

I tried `for /r %%i in (*) do execute.ps1`

However this did not work. I got an error :

> "Command execute.ps1 is either misspelled or could not be found."

Comment: You can use a `FOR /R` command to recursively search for your powershell script.

Comment: I tried `for /r %%i in (*) do execute.ps1`, however this did not work. I got an error "Command execute.ps1 is either misspelled or could not be found."

Comment: You need to use the `FOR` variable: `%%i`.  Been a while since I have used powershell but I also thought you have to use `powershell.exe myscript.ps1` to execute the script.  You also need to tell the for command what file to search for.  Otherwise it will iterate all files.

Comment: From the main folder, are the sub-folders just one deep? `c:\mainfolder\subfolder1\`  Or could the powershell script be nested 2 or 3 folders down?

Comment: Only one subfolder

Comment: And **ALL** sub-folders have the powershell script in it?

Comment: Thats correct, all subfolders have the same ps-script inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

@echo off

for /r /d %%f in (*) do pushd "%%f" & Call powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File execute.ps1 & popd

pause